# Installing Trackmania 2 using PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Until today, actually yesterday, *Trackmania 2* worked very well with *PlayOnLinux* using *Wine 2.7* (it is not in the list of compatible games, but believe me it did work very well :-)). Until yesterday... Today an update was released and playing *Trackmania 2* with PlayOnLinux seems to be impossible. Any hint of how to modify the configuration ? I am not talking about *Trackmania Forever* which still works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the answer was deleted. It was correct ! The new version of Trackmania 2 uses DirectX 11 which is not yet implemented in wine: see https://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40918&hilit=wine for more details. The old version of Trackmania 2 used DirectX 9.